# Targeting the last PARENT table-row (tr), not the CHILD table-row (tr)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to target the last parent table row within a table that has children table-row elements inside of it. I've tried the below jQuery to target the :last pseudo, however, like expected, it is targeting the absolute last table-row element within the targets parent table.

```
$('table[id*="dgRegistrantList"]').find('tr:last').addClass('EventRegLastAttendee')
```

I've put together a jsFiddle with the HTML block I'm attempting to target with the jQuery, I hope it is helpful!
http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/LZA7e/

[image: Green = Target; Red = Ignore]
The Green table-row is the one I would like to target, however, the one highlighted in Red is the obvious one receiving the class.

This system can generate a variant of table rows depending on the users selection prior to this "Step". For a full example of what I'm working with, visit: http://secure.massgeneral.org/event-form (I'm working with Step 2).

**Please be aware that the HTML I'm working with is produced by a CMS software that I as the customer, do not have access to changing. Hence the purpose of this jQuery exercise.**

Comment: Q: What am I trying to do?
A: I'm going to be adding a border to separate the rows for better understanding, however, I would like the LAST table-row to not inherit the CSS border. You can see the current implementation of the border by navigating to the secure.massgeneral.org/event-form path.

Comment: FYI - This is being targeted for responsive mobile design. In order to see the CSS and UI I'm working with, please resize your browser to a mobile phone resolution (max-width: 767px).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the parent `<tr>` elements have the classes `BBListOddRowStyle` or `BBListEvenRowStyle`  you can do this:

```
$('table[id*="dgRegistrantList"]').find('tr[class*=RowStyle]:last')
    .addClass('EventRegLastAttendee')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/NfeRU/1/)**

If not, you can use `.children()` twice to make sure you target the right ones:

```
$('table[id*="dgRegistrantList"]').children('tbody')
    .children('tr:last').addClass('EventRegLastAttendee')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/NfeRU/)**

Comment: darkajax, the second demo you outlined worked great. I would be hesitant to use the first approach as I honestly don't know how the system generates those classes and appends them to the table-rows. With my research and experience with the BBNC tool up until the point, never assume!

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to target the last row:

```
$('table[id*="dgRegistrantList"]').find('tr[class^=BBList][class$=RowStyle]:last').addClass('EventRegLastAttendee')
```

**Explanation**:

```
tr //it will look for tr
[class^=BBList] //which class starts with BBList
[class$=RowStyle] //and ends with RowStyle (so we're leaving Odd and Even inside and not recognized)
:last //the last of those element, if you remove it you select all of them
```

Comment: Will this work if there are embedded tables with `BBList` style `tr`s?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I ended up using the darkajax approach, but I will +1 for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Is .children() what you're looking to do?

```
$('table[id*="dgRegistrantList"]').children('tr:last').addClass('EventRegLastAttendee');
```

.children() only goes down one dom level, while .find() will go down as far as it can.

Comment: I just attempted this and it didn't seem to work properly. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/LZA7e/4/

Comment: I ended up using the second approach by darkajax! +1 for your efforts however!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `find`. It will look at any depth and it may match unintended subtables. Perhaps it will work for your example, but you don't want to be acquiring a bad habit. Plus, `find` will be more costly than a targeted approach.

You want a more targeted approach:

```
var targetTd = $('table[id*="dgRegistrantList"]').children('tbody').children('tr:last').find('table:first').children('tbody').children('td:last');
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and explanation! I like how you created a var specific to this event. I might change up my approach and use this in the future! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

use this code to target parent tr last row

```
$('table[id*="dgRegistrantList"]').find('tr[class^=BBList]:last').addClass('EventRegLastAttendee');
```

Comment: Thanks Mathi for your efforts, I ended up using the darkajax second approach. I will +1 for your efforts friend! Thanks!